# Overleaf Cases: There are more than one short label

Tags: beamer, labels, enumitem

My following Beamer script in Overleaf encounters an error: Package enumitem Error: Extra short label ignored, which says that "There are more than one short label" in the included frame. What's wrong with my script? Please help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=yellow,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Pengetahuan Kita Sebelumnya}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
Selain menggunakan definisi untuk menjawab pertanyaan kunci, kita juga bisa menggunakan \textbf{proposisi yang telah terbukti sebelumnya}.
\end{exampleblock}
Sebagai contoh, diberikan proposisi berikut.
\begin{block}{Proposisi 2}
Jika segitiga siku-siku $RST$ dengan panjang sisi $r$ dan $s$ serta panjang hipotenusa $t$ memenuhi $t =\sqrt{2rs},$ maka segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
\end{block}
\begin{enumerate}[Hipotesis \textbf{A}:, leftmargin=3.2cm, itemsep=2pt]
\item Segitiga siku-siku $RST$ dengan panjang sisi $r$ dan $s$ serta panjang hipotenusa $t$ memenuhi $t =\sqrt{2rs}.$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[Konklusi \textbf{B}:, leftmargin=3.2cm,  itemsep=2pt]
\item Segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
\end{enumerate}
Akan dibuktikan bahwa $A \Rightarrow B.$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `enumitem` package is not compatible with `beamer`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `enumitem` with beamer, they aren't compatible and also unnecessary as beamer has its own mechanism for enumerate label templates.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

{
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setlength{\leftmargini}{2.3cm}
\begin{enumerate}[{Hipotesis} A:]
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However in your case, it looks as if a `description` might actually be more suited than a modified enumeration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\usecolortheme{default}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=yellow,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Pengetahuan Kita Sebelumnya}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
Selain menggunakan definisi untuk menjawab pertanyaan kunci, kita juga bisa menggunakan \textbf{proposisi yang telah terbukti sebelumnya}.
\end{exampleblock}
Sebagai contoh, diberikan proposisi berikut.
\begin{block}{Proposisi 2}
Jika segitiga siku-siku $RST$ dengan panjang sisi $r$ dan $s$ serta panjang hipotenusa $t$ memenuhi $t =\sqrt{2rs},$ maka segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
\end{block}
\begin{description}
\item[Hipotesis \textbf{A}:] Segitiga siku-siku $RST$ dengan panjang sisi $r$ dan $s$ serta panjang hipotenusa $t$ memenuhi $t =\sqrt{2rs}.$
\end{description}
\begin{description}
\item[Konklusi \textbf{B}:] Segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
\end{description}
Akan dibuktikan bahwa $A \Rightarrow B.$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other comments:

- you don't need to load `graphicx`, the `default` color theme or `hyperref`, beamer automatically loads all of them for you

Answer (score 0):

Just analysis, no solution yet:

- if I delete the first enumerate-environment, it compiles (see screenshot)
- if I try commenting out options in the first enumerate, I get capacity-problems, i.e. it doesn't compile
- this is strange, as it's not too different from the second one.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=yellow,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Pengetahuan Kita Sebelumnya}
    \begin{exampleblock}{}
        Selain menggunakan definisi untuk menjawab pertanyaan kunci, kita       juga bisa menggunakan \textbf{proposisi yang telah terbukti                 sebelumnya}.
    \end{exampleblock}
Sebagai contoh, diberikan proposisi berikut.

    \begin{block}{Proposisi 2}
        Jika segitiga siku-siku $RST$ dengan panjang sisi $r$ dan $s$               serta panjang hipotenusa $t$ memenuhi $t =\sqrt{2rs},$ maka             segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
    \end{block}

% deleting the first enumerate environment
    
    \begin{enumerate}[Konklusi \textbf{B}:, leftmargin=3.2cm,                       itemsep=2pt]
        \item Segitiga $RST$ sama kaki.
    \end{enumerate}

Akan dibuktikan bahwa $A \Rightarrow B.$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in the label is interpreted as the counter label, but you have two `i`s.  If you put in a second item, then its label becomes `Hiipotesiis A`.  Instead, you want to protect the `i` from being interpreted as a counter label by putting it in `{}`, and change the `A` to `\Alph*` to indicate it should increment.  (But if you're explicitly setting your labels, why not use `itemize` with `\item[Hipotesis \textbf{A}:]`?)

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[{Hipotesis} \textbf{\Alph*}:, leftmargin=3cm]
%\begin{enumerate}[Hipotesis \textbf{A}:, leftmargin=3cm]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sampel output]

(Note that enumitem is not compatible with beamer, so you may run into other problems.)